# An array resets when I submit the second value

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

When I add a value to the array and console.log it the first value gets removed and the array restarts always leaving the array with one value. How can I add multiple values by clicking the same button each time?

```
function calcBudget(){

    //expenseCostValue is an input in a form.     
    const expenseValue = expenseCostValue.value;
    const itemList = [];
    itemList.push(expenseValue); 
    console.log(itemList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably redefining your array every time. Put the `const itemList = []` outside of the click event handler. and just run `itemList.push(expenseValue)` inside the click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

*You must change the scope of your Array*

```js
function calcBudget() {
  const expenseValue = expenseCostValue.value;
  const itemList = []; // → remove the array

  console.log(itemList);
}
```

```js
const itemList = []; // we declare it out of our function

function calcBudget() {
  const expenseValue = expenseCostValue.value;
  itemList.push(expenseValue);

  console.log(itemList);
}
```

*I hope I have been helpful*